# UICollectionView new items insertions remaining on the current item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, collectionview

I use UICollectionView in my project to show news feed. When I move to the top of collection view I can load 20 older posts with pull to refresh gesture. My issue is when I load older posts the oldest post (collection view cell) appears at the top of the collection view. What I want is to start from the point where I made pull to refresh gesture.

I use DeepDiff library in my project for reloading collection view

```
   self.collectionView.reload(changes: changes, updateData: {
   self.cellViewModels = layout.viewModels
   })
```

Here's a link to a video describing my problem: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlfWrjF-RDo

Comment: after older news uploaded call collectionView.scrollToItem(at: path, at: .top, animated: false)

Comment: when you reload. How do you handle your dataSource inside                       
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 0):

This is how reload works. I now that social network and messangers use reversed collection view with rotation and when you pull to refresh you add new posts to the end of dataSource and your visible area doesn't "jump" to the top.

You can check this: [UICollectionView reverse Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704191/uicollectionview-reverse-layout)

P.S. You can scroll, but it can be look bad